# How can I get current updated browser history using python?

Tags: python, browser, tracking, history, browser-history

I used browser-history package to get history of web browsers.
But I could not get real time history.
Its updating speed is too low.
Although I opened new url, it shows same urls.
This is my code.

```
import browser_history

while True:
    outputs = browser_history.get_history()

    print(outputs.to_csv())
```

How can I get fast speed updating history of browser using python?

Comment: Which browser are you using?

Comment: Firefox, Safari, Opera, Chrome, Edge...

Comment: The Browser history is stored in a local database file and is freely accessible. Your browser reads and writes data to the file every time you use the browser.  You'll probably have to close the browser to ensure that the file gets updated.

Comment: I want tracking.

Comment: @bituniverse you can't have tracking

Comment: Please tell me how to catch current input url of browser using python.